# Minimum paths on graph with probabilistic costs

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a graph where costs on arcs are random variables with normal distribution and mean/variance that are themselves random variables (they are estimated from finite sample). The graph is strongly connected. Given any two nodes consider a problem of finding minimum cost path between the two nodes.

I suspect that given the uncertainty in costs on individual arcs the cost of the minimum path is going to be underestimated on average. This is a conjecture at the moment.

Has this been shown in rigorous way? I have searched for it without luck, but it might be the case that I just don't what keyword to look for (or I am wrong, of course).

Comment: What do you want to minimize exactly ?  The expected value of the path ?

Comment: Yes, expected cost of a path (which is sum of expected costs across all arcs in the path).

Comment: OK.  And can you clarify what you mean by 'underestimated' ?

Comment: The sum of expected costs on individual arcs is expected cost for a complete path, this comes from linearity of expectations. However, when we have a set of tentative paths, we will choose the one with minimal expected cost. I believe that cost of this path will be, on average, lower than real cost of the path (after the uncertainty is removed). For example, consider having large bpdy of candodate paths whose differences between their costs is negligble when compared to uncertainty in them. Then you essentially can't tell which one is the best, but you still choose the path with lowest cost.

Comment: Using the term "on average" is confusing me...because  the cost of a given path, on average, will be exactly its expected value.  So there's no underestimation here.  Or do you mean by 'uncertainty' that the distributions/mean/variance that you have are not the correct values, but only estimations ?  If so, I don't think there's any way to find an answer - it's too dependent on the dataset and real distributions.